# Is there a classical version of Yetter-Drinfeld modules?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, hopf-algebras, bialgebras

One motivation for the notion of the Drinfeld double $D(H)$ of an Hopf algebra $H$ is that it is defined exactly so that modules over $D(H)$ correspond to Yetter-Drinfeld modules over $H$.

If we think of Lie bialgebras as the "classical approximation" to quantum groups, there is also a classical version of the Drinfeld double construction where the double of $\mathfrak{g}$ is $\mathfrak{g} \oplus \mathfrak{g}^*$ as a vector space, with $\mathfrak{g}, \mathfrak{g}^*$ being subalgebras and
$$[X,Y]= \text{ad}_X^*(Y)-\text{ad}_Y^*(X)$$
for $X\in \mathfrak{g}$, $Y\in \mathfrak{g}^*$.

> Is there are classical version of notion of the notion of Yetter-Drinfeld module, so that Yetter-Drinfeld modules over a Lie bialgebra $\mathfrak{g}$ correspond to usual modules over the classical Drinfeld double of $\mathfrak{g}$?

If there is such a notion, it should probably be a vector space equipped with a module structure over both $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{g}^*$, with some compatibility condition, but I am not sure what compatibility condition we should put here.

Comment: Yes there is, see eg section 2.8 of this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.09744

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I was looking for!